# O que são "colunas geradas" no MySQL e quais seriam as suas aplicações?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Eu fiz o download da nova versão do MySQL workbench e quando estava criando uma tabela, notei uma nova propriedade do campo que se chama de **Generated Column**.

No site do MySQL diz que se trata de uma implementação nova do **MySQL 5.7.5**, mas não ficou muito claro para mim a sua utilização e onde ela pode ser útil. Alguém poderia explicar?

[image: SS]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

São colunas calculadas. Estas colunas não devem ser atualizados por você, elas sempre terão o valor definido baseado nos dados das outras colunas. É um facilitador para acessar uma determinada informação que é usada com frequência e precisaria sempre ter uma expressão para obtê-la.

É possível que ela seja **virtual** e o valor será calculado toda vez que acessá-la. Ou pode ser **armazenada**, onde o cálculo é feito sempre que uma das colunas usadas na sua fórmula for atualizada. Obviamente é mais rápido para acessar, mas ocupa mais espaço em disco e memória, já que o valor calculado fica armazenado. Cada caso tem um uso melhor.

É muito fácil abusar disto. É útil, mas dá para viver sem, sempre deu.

```
CREATE TABLE venda ( 
    nome VARCHAR(30),  
    preco DECIMAL(10, 2),
    qtde INT,
    total DECIMAL(10, 2) AS (preco * qtde)); //tem seu valor gerado por esta fórmula
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/ComputedColumn.sql).

Ela pode ser bem útil para uso em índices que precisa ser uma expressão. [Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) ([secundário](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html)).

Comment: No caso de não ser definido algum deles (preco ou qtde). Dá algum erro? Ou é melhor definir um valor defualt para essa coluna?

Comment: Dá erro, claro, tem que existir. Não tem porque e nem pode colocar um valor *default*.

Comment: Haa ok, não conhecia, vejo a utilidade disto. Obrigado

Comment: Mas qual a diferença para uma view? POdemos aplicar a mesma formula qtde*preço numa coluna total . Correto?

Comment: É parecido, mas isto já está na tabela. A *view* serve para outras coisas também, pode fazer coisas mais complexas. Nem sempre precisa da *view*, ela pode ser um canhão para matar passarinho em muitos casos. Se for armazenado (não me pergunte porque não pode se for virtual, coisas do MySQL) você pode usar a coluna em um índice ou outros lugares que a *view* não pode ser aplicada.